# Bonding with 2 NIC's and 2 reserves?

Tags: linux, nic, bonding

I have a server with 4 ports (2 adapters with two ports each). I want to connect two ports to the local switch and two other ports to the external switch. This local switch has an uplink to the external switch, which has access to the net. As the local switch has a faster connection (1 Gb), I want to use it as primary switch using the two ports. If this switch fails, I want that the following two ports, that are connected with the external switch, will get activated.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2009/10/linux-nic-bonding.html

Answer (score 1):

Any bonding mode that doesn't require a configuration on the switch will work. Consider mode-1 for example.

Comment: It sounds as though he wants a mode-1 bond of a pair of mode-4 bonds.  The networking equivalent of RAID 10, I guess.

Comment: That wouldn't be possible with only two NICs.  My guess is that he wants two bonds interconnected with two switches, which is quite a trivial and common configuration. If those were advanced switches in a stach, I'd say go for mode-4, but since they are different, mode-1 seems to be the right thing to do

Comment: Christpher did understand me well. I prefere mode 0 in place of mode 4, as the switch probably does not support the mode 4 standard.

If I use 4 ports in mode 0 (H.A., Load Balancing), the switches won't work well as packets from the same IP will be send to the two switches.

Mode 1 that uses 2 active ports and two passive ports, is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: So what I want to do is a mode 1 on two mode 0's. An image: [IMG]http://i48.tinypic.com/2dadmhd.jpg[/IMG]

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible. you have to specify the nic with connection to the faster switch as primary. [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/static/linux-ethernet-bonding-driver-howto.php) is a bonding how-to.